# Swift Firebase Get childByAutoId Key When Setting

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to obtain the `.childByAutoId()` key value while I am setting a firebase value. Is this possible to do or do I have to recall firebase again to retrieve it?

```
ref.child("users").child(user.id).child("alerts").childByAutoId().setValue(["autoID" : .childByAutoIdValue])
```

For Example: I need the AutoId that it generates but would like to obtain it while setting a firebase value.

```
let keyValue = ref.childByAutoId.key //Completley wrong but to better understand what im trying to do
```

***Update:** This is how i achieved what I was trying to do.

```
let keyValue = ref.child("users").child(user.id).child("alerts").childByAutoId().key

ref.child("users").child(user.id).child("alerts").child(keyValue).setValue(["autoID" : keyValue])
```

used `keyValue` in replacement of `childByAutoId()`

Comment: I tried this but it gives me different ID. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()

let keyValue = self.ref.child(name_of_child).childByAutoId().key
```

Comment: i updated the code for better understanding look inside .setValue() for what im trying to do.

Comment: what you can do is get the key and use it where you need it, it is used to use the same key in several child

Comment: I tried this but it gives me different ID. Do you know why?